# How to display pictures on excel with a click on a cell?

Tags: excel, vba

The following code makes me able to select only one cell (in this case A3), click on a button and bring a picture. The nagative thing is that i need it to work also on other cells (from A3 to A22) and i don't know how to modify the code in order to do so. Any suggestions? Thank you

```
Private Sub cmdDisplayPhoto_Click()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim myObj
    Dim Pictur
    Set myObj = ActiveSheet.DrawingObjects
    For Each Pictur In myObj
    If Left(Pictur.Name, 7) = "Picture" Then
    Pictur.Select
    Pictur.Delete
    End If
    Next

    Dim Exercise As String, T As String

    myDir = "C:\Users\Computer\Desktop\Pictures of Exercises\"
    Exercise = Range("A3")
    T = ".PNG"

    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddPicture Filename:=myDir & Exercise & T, linktofile:=msoFalse, savewithdocument:=msoTrue, Left:=770, Top:=60, Width:=160, Height:=150
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    End Sub
```

Comment: So you want to highlight a cell, say A10, and the code will bring the picture named in that cell?

Comment: I want to select cell A3, click on the button and bring a picture, then I want cell A15, so i go there select the cell and click the button for a different picture. This mechanism should work from cell A3 till cell A22.

Comment: Change this line`Exercise = Range("A3")` to `Exercise = Selection`

Comment: Very simply it works fine

Answer (score 0):

Try changing...

```
Exercise = Range("A3")
```

to

```
if ActiveCell.column = 1 then Exercise = ActiveCell Else Exit Sub
```

This will use the text of whatever cell is selected for the picture and only accept cells from column A.